# How can I generate barcode with JsBarcode.js and print it on a PDF file using Kartik mPDF within Yii framework 2.0

Tags: javascript, php, yii2, barcode, mpdf

I have installed `Kartik mPDF` extension within `Yii framework 2.0`. Below is the code snippet within my controller that generates PDF file and send it to the browser.

```
// setup kartik\mpdf\Pdf component
    $pdf = new Pdf([
        'mode' => Pdf::MODE_CORE, 
        'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_A4, 
        'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_PORTRAIT, 
        'destination' => Pdf::DEST_BROWSER, 

        // your html content input
        'content' => $this->renderPartial('print-barcode'),  

        'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
        'cssInline' => '.kv-heading-1{font-size:18px}', 
        'options' => ['title' => 'My PDF file'],
        'methods' => [ 
            'SetHeader'=>['My header'], 
            'SetFooter'=>['{PAGENO}'],
        ]
    ]);

    return $pdf->render();
```

I have two JS files (`JsBarcode.js` and `CODE128.js`) which can be found here https://github.com/lindell/JsBarcode 
To generate barcode I need to include these JS files and my custom JavaScript code. In my view, I normally include those files as follows (my `print-barcode.php`).

```
<?php
$this->registerJsFile(Yii::$app->urlManager->baseUrl . '/js/JsBarcode.js', ['depends' => [\yii\web\JqueryAsset::className()]]);
$this->registerJsFile(Yii::$app->urlManager->baseUrl . '/js/Code128.js', ['depends' => [\yii\web\JqueryAsset::className()]]);

$jsGenerateBarcode = 'My custom Javascript code goes here ...';
$this->registerJs($jsGenerateBarcode, $this::POS_END);
?>
```

All the included JavaScript code does not have any effect at all, since it is a PDF file and not a webpage. How can I print the barcode generated by `JsBarcode.js` and by `CODE128.js` and pass it on the PDF file which is generated by `kartik\mpdf\Pdf;`?

Comment: I don't have much experience with javascript. But I think it runs when the page is loaded. Which is after the .php has loaded. You could pass the generated value from the barcode to the `.php` with an Ajax request and retrieve the `.pdf` file that way.

Comment: the barcode is generated by the Javascript plugin and the Javascript plugin is included on the view. How can I generate the barcode before the view is loaded. That means I don't have the barcode yet to pass on the view before the view is loaded. Only if I find the way how to include the Javascript code in the controller before rendering the view.

Comment: That's what I meant, the javascript loads after the php. You will need an alternative plugin which is either PHP based. Or use an Ajax call to pass the barcode to the php file which generates the pdf file and retrieve the rendered pdf.

Comment: Well it is not possible (and already been asked) since mPdf do not support js (or just basic js)... You should use instead a chart library able to export charts as image (e.g. highcharts).

Comment: If you want to generate barcode then i suggest you to use: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-barcode-generator-8-types/

Comment: @Insane Skull: yes I did try that extension. It works great but I don't know know to get the barcode on a PDF file since I use mPDF pluging to generate the PDF file. Another solution is to first save each barcode as PNG file and pass the path of the PNG file to the PDF file. But I don't know how to save each barcode as PNG file. In general, how can I generate barcode and also print it on a PDF file?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry so late, but this works for me. You should create a view with the information first, then use renderPartial and sent that to mpdf.

My View contains:

```
<script src="<?=yii::$app->params['rootUrl']?>/js/JsBarcode.code128.min.js"></script>

<p>Safety is Everyone's Responsibility</p>
<p><barcode code="<?=$model->qrcode?>" type="C128A" class="barcode" size="0.8" /></p>
```

And to test:

```
return $this->renderPartial('_print-view',['model'=>$myModel]);
```

And Finally to print the pdf (I was printing Badges so i was playing with margins):

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([  
//'mode' => 'c'
'margin_left' => 0,
'margin_right' => 0,
'margin_top' => 0,
'margin_bottom' => 0,
'format' => [54,86],
]);

$mpdf->SetTitle('Badge: '.$myModel->badge_number);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($this->renderPartial('_print-view',['model'=>$myModel,'page'=>1]));

$mpdf->AddPage('L');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($this->renderPartial('_print-view',['model'=>$myModel,'page'=>2]));

$mpdf->Output($badge_number,'I');
```